# when I ues pycharm2019 jupyter notebook to open .ipynb file，the window can't interact and stuck

Tags: pycharm

when I ues pycharm2019 jupyter notebook to open .ipynb file，the window can't interact and stuck,show 'Loading' in edit screen

Comment: Which programming language is used in the notebook? Could you please create a ticket in PyCharms bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY and attach `idea.log` from **Help | Show Log in ...**?